# How to change font color of Navbar items in Dash

Tags: python, css, navbar

I created a Dash Navbar similar to the custom_default one in this example: https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/blob/main/examples/python/advanced-component-usage/navbars.py .

How can I edit the font color of the menu items? Note: they are links (I think that might make a difference).

Thanks!

Comment: Remember to spend the time to write [a good post](/help/how-to-ask): if you have a problem. show the [mcve] code _in your post_ so that others can both see what you're doing, and tell whether or not they have the same problem, by looking at your post and nothing else. Only add external links _in addition_ to having all the details relevant to your problem in your post.